# An exact sequence from Koszul complex

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $x$ denote the sequence $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ and $x^{'}$ denote $(x_1,\ldots,x_m,y)$. Then we have the following exact sequence of Koszul homologies: (set I=$(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$)

$0\to H_1(x)/yH_1(x)\to H_1(x^{'})\to R/I\to R/I\to 0.$

Suppose the ring is local and  $y\in (I:m)\setminus I$. Then I have come across the following exact sequence while reading a note.

$0\to H_1(x)/yH_1(x)\to H_1(x^{'})\to R/(I:y)\to 0.$

Can someone explain how do we get the last term? Thanks.

Comment: What is the map for the $R/I \to R/I$ in the first exact sequence?